# (Extract/Separate/Match) Groups in Any Order

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, tidyr, stringr

```
# Sample Data Frame
df  <- data.frame(Column_A 
                  =c("1011 Red Cat", 
                     "Mouse 2011 is in the House 3001", "Yellow on Blue Dog walked around Park"))
```

I've a column of manually inputted data which I'm trying to clean.

```
  Column_A 
1|1011 Red Cat                         |
2|Mouse 2011 is in the House 3001      |
2|Yellow on Blue Dog walked around Park|
```

I want to separate each characteristic into it's own column, but still maintain Column A to pull out other characteristics later.

```
  Colour               Code           Column_A
1|Red                 |1001          |Cat
2|NA                  |2001 3001     |Mouse is in the House
3|Yellow on Blue      |NA            |Dog walked around Park
```

To date, I've been re-ordering them with gsub and capturing groups, then using Tidyr::extract to separate them.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df1 <- df %>% 

  # Reorders the Colours
  mutate(Column_A = gsub("(.*?)?(Yellow|Blue|Red)(.*)?", "\\2 \\1\\3", 
                         Column_A, perl = TRUE)) %>%
  # Removes Whitespaces 
  mutate(Column_A =str_squish(Column_A)) %>%
  # Extracts the Colours 
  extract(Column_A, c("Colour", "Column_A"), "(Red|Yellow|Blue)?(.*)") %>%

  # Repeats the Prececding Steps for Codes
  mutate(Column_A = gsub("(.*?)?(\\b\\d{1,}\\b)(.*)?", "\\2 \\1\\3", 
                         Column_A, perl = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(Column_A =str_squish(Column_A)) %>%
  extract(Column_A, c("Code", "Column_A"), "(\\b\\d{1,}\\b)?(.*)") %>%
  mutate(Column_A = str_squish(Column_A))
```

Which Results in this:

```
Colour      Code    Column_A
|Red        |1011   |Cat
|Yellow     |NA     |on Blue Dog walked around Park
|NA         |1011   |Mouse is in the House 1001
```

This works fine for the first row, but not the proceeding space and word separated ones, which I've subsequently been extracting and uniting. What's a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: for the code you could do `a = trimws(gsub("\\s+"," ",gsub("\\D"," ",df$Column_A)))`

Comment: for the color you could do `b = sub("(.*(Red|Yellow|Blue)).*","\\1",sub("^((?!(Blue|Red|Yellow)).)*","",as.matrix(df),perl = TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks, but I really need the information from Column A removed too. Have something similar from the Tidyverse too.

`mutate(Colour= sapply(str_extract_all(Column_A,"Red|Yellow|Blue"),paste, collapse=" "))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` we can do

```
library(tidyverse)

colors <- paste0(c("Red", "Yellow", "Blue"), collapse = "|")

df %>%
   mutate(Color = str_extract(Column_A,
                   paste0("(", colors, ").*(", colors, ")|(", colors, ")")),
           Code = str_extract_all(Column_A, "\\d+", ), 
           Column_A = pmap_chr(list(Color, Code, Column_A), function(x, y, z) 
              trimws(gsub(paste0("\\b", c(x,  y), "\\b", collapse = "|"), "", z))), 
           Code = map_chr(Code, paste, collapse = " "))


#                 Column_A         Color      Code
#1                    Cat            Red      1011
#2 Mouse  is in the House           <NA> 2011 3001
#3 Dog walked around Park Yellow on Blue
```

We first extract text between two `colors` using `str_extract`. You can include all the possible colors which can occur in the data in `colors`. We use `paste0` to construct the regex. For this example it would be

```
paste0("(", colors, ").*(", colors, ")|(", colors, ")")
#[1] "(Red|Yellow|Blue).*(Red|Yellow|Blue)|(Red|Yellow|Blue)"
```

meaning extract text between and including `colors` or extract only `colors`.

For `Code` part as we can have multiple `Code` values, we use `str_extract_all` and get all the numbers from the column. This part is initially stored in a list.

For `Column_A` values we remove everything which was selected in `Code` and `Color` adding word boundaries using `gsub` and the remaining part is saved.

As we had stored `Code` in list previously, we convert them to one string by collapsing them. This returns empty strings for values that do not match. You can convert them back to `NA` by adding `Code = replace(Code, Code == "", NA))` in the chain if needed.

Comment: Works perfectly, you just need to change 'Colour' to Color in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with a combination of `stringr` and `gsub`, using a list of colours supplied in R:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# list of colours from R colors()
cols <- as.character(colors())

apply(df,
      1,
      function(x)

        tibble(
          # Exctract CSV of colours
          Color = cols[cols %in% str_split(tolower(x), " ", simplify = T)] %>%
            paste0(collapse = ","),

          # Extract CSV of sequential lists of digits
          Code = str_extract_all(x, regex("\\d+"), simplify = T) %>%
            paste0(collapse = ","),

          # Remove colours and digits from Column_A
          Column_A = gsub(paste0("(\\d+|",
                                 paste0(cols, collapse = "|"),
                                 ")"), "", x, ignore.case = T) %>% trimws())) %>%
  bind_rows()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Color       Code      Column_A                  
  <chr>       <chr>     <chr>                     
1 red         1011      Cat                       
2 ""          2011,3001 Mouse  is in the House    
3 blue,yellow ""        on  Dog walked around Park
```